# Rails 4 contact form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup a basic contact form in Rails and it keeps throwing this error:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

```
Extracted source (around line #1):
<%= form_for contact do |f| %>
<div>
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Here is my code.

I'm rendering a partial with this:

```
<%= render 'form', :contact => @contact %>
```

This is the partial:

```
<%= form_for contact do |f| %>
<div>
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :email %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :message %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :message %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.submit "Send" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my model, contact.rb

```
class Contact
extend ActiveModel::Naming
include ActiveModel::Conversion
include ActiveModel::Validations

attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

validates :name, 
        :presence => true

validates :email,
        :format => { :with => /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

validates :message,
        :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 1000 }

def initialize(attributes = {})
attributes.each do |name, value|
  send("#{name}=", value)
end
end

def deliver
return false unless valid?
true
end

def persisted?
false
end
end
```

And my controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

def new
@contact = Contact.new
end

def create
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
if @contact.deliver
  flash.now[:error] = nil
  flash.now[:notice] = "Thanks for contacting us! We'll get back to you within 24 hours!."
else
  flash.now[:error] = "Hmm. We couldn't send your message. Double check that you filled in the whole form."
  render :new
end
end

end
```

Thanks in advance for your help! I've scoured SO and haven't been able to fix this so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render the form as a partial instead and use the `locals` option to pass your variable:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {contact: @contact} %>
```

Comment: Are you sure `@contact` is not empty? Try adding a `<%= @contact.inspect %>` and comment out the render tag to see if the `@contact` variable contains anything.

Comment: Ah -- that shows 'nil', so I guess it's empty. Given the code above, do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is happening when you access the new action of the contacts controller. Try using the rails console (`rails c`) and create a contact manually by entering `c = Contact.new`. Then you should be able to see if something is failing when a new contact is being created.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for nil do |f| %>
<%= form_for [] do |f| %>
```

My guess here is that your @contact is set to nil and that it doesn't come from your Contact#new action.

it would simply work if you do this:

```
<%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>
```

Though it is not recommended.

You need to check that the view containing your form is actually rendered by the new action of your ContactController. For more info see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2451